# Perl HTTP::Request and Server Down

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that is supposed to use HTTP::Response to grab an XML file and then parse it. The script works great, except when it can't reach the server its trying to get the info from. 
I know I have to have an error checking and if an error does exist, use a return to continue on with the loop, I have done with with NET::SNMP and SSH, but I can't seem to get it working for this scenario. I'm about to be pull my hair in frustration. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use Net::SNMP;
use XML::Simple;
use HTTP::Status;

$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

if ( open ( FH, "DeviceList.txt" ) )
{
    while ( defined ( my $line = <FH> ) )
    {
            $line =~ s/\s+$//;
            $device = $line;
            &checkcon;
    }
    close FH;
}
else
{
    print "DeviceList.txt file not found\n";
}
#exit;

 sub checkcon
 {

my ($req, $error) = HTTP::Request->new(GET => 'https://'.$device.'/getxml?location=/HelloWorld');
$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_verify_mode => SSL_VERIFY_NONE);
$ua->timeout(10);
$req->authorization_basic('test', 'test');
$test = $ua->request($req)->content;

print $req;


if ($test =~ "parser error") {
     print "No Workie\n";
return;
 }

#if (!is_success ($req))
#{
#print "No Workie!";
#return;
#}

# create object
my $xml = new XML::Simple;

# read XML file
my $data = $xml->XMLin("$test");

print "Looping";
# access XML data
`echo "$device,$data->{Hello}{World}{content}" >> Test.txt`;

}
exit 0;
```